# Accessing shared folder asks me credentials

Tags: network-shares, smb

I have a shared folder on a Win 2003 server: user ***Guest*** can access in read-only mode.
On the network I have many different pc with different OS (Win8, Seven, XP) and almost all can access that folder to download some app without any prompt.

There's some XP SP3 Professional pc behaving in a strange way: if I open explorer.exe and navigate to **\\my_server_name\shared_folder** I am asked for credentials... why?
If I provide ***Guest*** as user with ***blank password*** I can access that folder; restarting pc leads me to the starting point, with credentials popping up...

On the command prompt, using `nslookup my_server_name` I receive **my_server_ip**, so problem is not DNS...

Why every Windows Seven pc can access without any problem, while only some XP behaves in this way?

Comment: I would check if the network is set as Public, Home or Office in each computer.

Comment: @AlejandroAngelico: both Win2003 and WinXP don't have that difference in firewall... am I wrong?

Comment: I was talking about the network configuration. I really cant remember Windows XP, but in W7 and W8 when you connect to a network for the first time, you choose "Public", "Office" or "Private" (or something like that). This impacts in the sharing behavior.